# Leave Requests - How to handle Cancellations

Tags: calendar

I have a leave request on Sharepoint 2013 that works fairly well.  Workflow is started once user submits information on list, if approved, email is sent to supervisor and requester. It is also automatically added on 2 calendars. One for Staff that can view how is off and for how long, and the other for Admin Only that can view more detail such as leave type or employee comments.

My question is how do I handle cancellations?  Is there a way the employee can go to the staff calendar, delete their time off, and then an email also be sent to the employee and supervisor advising that the time off has been canceled?  Also, I would need it to delete the scheduled time off from the Admin Calendar as well.

Please help. If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Workflows run after the triggering event, so there's really no workflows for delete. A solution is to either add a Yes/No column for "Please Cancel", or if you already have a status column, add a Cancel status. Then have a second workflow that watches for changes to the item and the selection of the cancel request. It would then send followup emails and clean up the lists/calendars.